# Google Analytics Site Search in BigQuery

Tags: excel, google-analytics, bigdata, analytics

I am currently trying to pull 1.000.000 different search queries in the next 12 months from a webshop in Google Analytics. Since you only can show 5.000 queries per page and the loading times and the manual export in Excel files are very troublesome, I am searching for a solution via Google BigQuery.

So I activated "Google Analytics API" in the Google Cloud Platform and am stuck now. Is there a fast and easy way to get a spreadsheet with the following?

1. Every single query
2. In the last 12 months
3. From a specific data view
4. optional: export as Excel

I would very much appreciate your support that would save me hours and hours of manual exports.

Cheers

Comment: There is no Analytics API in BigQuery, there is an Analytics API in Google Cloud (which is where you would also find BigQuery). So first you need to clarify if you want to use the API (which is a programmatic way of returning aggregated results) or BigQuery (which is a way of accessing hit level data and do you own aggregations, but will only work if you are a GA360 client or if you use GA4).

Comment: Hello Eike,
thank you for your support and answer! We do not use GA360 and GA4 and have not (yet) planned it. My goal is to simply export all search terms recorded in Google Analytics and then compare them with another table using an S reference. At the moment I can only export 5,000 search terms at once in Google Analytics - every time I repeat that, I lose about 5 minutes because of the loading times and data processing. However, a total of 1,000,000 search terms were recorded, so I would have to repeat the process 200 times.
Because of this, I'm looking for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

This feels like cheating, but if you need a simple solution that does not require programming or any setup, you can use the Google Analytics [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/query-explorer/).

This is a technology demo that demonstrates the use of the Google Analytics Reporting API, but it works well to get data from the analytics accounts that are connected to the Google Account your are logged in with in your browser.

If you visit the sites you will see a number of dropdowns - the first three allow you to select an account/property/view (you need the view, the other options are just to filter down to view level).

Then you can select a timeframe, metrics and dimensions. You need to select a metric (since you plan to query a hit level dimension you probably want to use page views. You have to select a metric even if you do not plan to use it) and a dimension - the relevant dimension is "ga:searchKeyWord".

Then you can click "run query", and download the result as tsv (tab separated values).

The API will return 10 000 results per query, but unlike the Analytics interface, this is blazing fast, so even with manual paging by changing the start index (or by changing the timeframe) downloading 1 mio results will take only a few minutes.

If you are doing this regularly, you probably want to run an API script and do this programmatically, but for a quick result the query explorer should do.

Comment: Hi @eike, thanks so much for your help, that already helps me do things much faster. Is there a way to run a script with it so I won't have to manually download and stitch 100 files together?